# associative array initialization via string and without declare

Tags: bash, associative-array, declare

I want to have a global associative array, that is filled at several locations and I can not get it to work to initialize the array with the content of a string without using the declare -A -g over and over at said locations(which I don't feel like is the smartest approach). I've extracted the issue to the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr
declare inputString

inputString="([key]=val)"

arr="$inputString"
printf "from variable: ${arr[*]}\n"
printf "from variable: ${arr[key]}\n"

arr=([key]=val)
printf "inline: ${arr[*]}\n"
printf "inline: ${arr[key]}\n"

declare -A arr=$inputString
printf "with declare: ${arr[*]}\n"
printf "with declare: ${arr[key]}\n"
```

the output is:

```
from variable: ([key]=val)
from variable: 
inline: val
inline: val
with declare: val
with declare: val
```

whereas I would expect it to be:

```
from variable: val
from variable: val
inline: val
inline: val
with declare: val
with declare: val
```

what do I have to do to accomplish this task?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you just want to be able to pass an associative array to functions, you can pass it by name and access it with `${!varname[key]}`

Comment: I try to "return" an associative array from a function. As there is no returnvalue I tried to accomplish that with echoing a proper associative array string and working with this string. There is the point to get an already declared array initialized with the string.

Comment: Don't try to return an associative array, just create it as a side effect. Bash doesn't have first class arrays, you can't assign one array to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One `bash 4.3+` approach using a `nameref`:

```
myadd() {                             # $1 == array name; $2 == key name; $3 == value
    declare -n _arr="$1"              # nameref
    _arr+=(["$2"]="$3")
}

myclear() {
    declare -n _arr="$1"
    _arr=()
}
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
unset      arr1 arr2
declare -A arr1 arr2

myadd arr1 keyX 3
myadd arr1 Index_45 16
myadd arr2 long_string_abc long_value_xyz

typeset -p arr1 arr2
    ==> declare -A arr1=([keyX]="3" [Index_45]="16" )
    ==> declare -A arr2=([long_string_abc]="long_value_xyz" )

myclear arr1

myadd arr1 aaa 111
myadd arr1 bbb 222

typeset -p arr1
    ==> declare -A arr1=([bbb]="222" [aaa]="111" )
```

Comment: thank you for your thoughts. You understood that correctly, as in I have a global array I want to populate on several locations. I am not sure about the "add to" instead of "rebuild from scratch" part though. I really want to reinitialize the global array, not just adding to it. I am aware, that I can do that value by value and via the declare -A. I was just wondering if it is okay to call the declare -A -g on all those points as this feels really wrong.

Comment: @roediGERhard 'add to' vs 'rebuild from scratch' was just added to limit the scope of the answer; I've added one idea for resetting/clearing the array (`myclear()`); the general idea would be to issue `declare -A` once (in the main script) and then for the rest of the script make use of functions and namerefs to 'add to' or 'clear' the array as needed

Comment: But how do I do that without handling every value for itself? In other words: can one "fill" an array with a string? If so, how?

Comment: where is the string coming from? in one of your other comments you mention a function that echoes a string (eg, `[key]=val`); it sounds (to me) like the function is building the string so, would it be as 'simple' as replacing the string-building-logic with calls to the function (or duplicating the content of the `myclear()/myadd()` functions in your function)

Comment: thank you again for your input. Yes I think it would be possible to call the clear/adder functions instead of building a string. Only downside: the function would always fill the same hardcoded array. If I could manage to fill an array with the string it would be a bit more dynamic, as I would be able to build an array where I need it instead of relying on always the same global array. I know the original question does state, that I want to fill a global array(which I want to do right now) but I wondered if I could build it in a way, that I can use it on other ocassions as well.

Comment: the function does not *`fill the same hardcoded array`*; the nameref is a reference to the real array; try: `declare -A arr1 arr2; myadd arr1 a 3; myadd arr2 b 5; typeset -p arr1 arr2` ... no changes to the function ... the same function populates 2 different arrays; 'fraid I don't understand the last part of your comment re: `'build/use it on other occasions'`

Comment: oh. I understand it now. Thank you for the hint again. I guess I'll fiddle around with that and think I know what I need to do.

Comment: streamlined the answer and updated with a dual array example